# Change the load order from addtocart block with the addto block

Tags: template, ce-1.9.1.0, xml, addtocart, local.xml

I getting crazy with the template system from Magento.

I tried to change the load-order of my "Add to Cart" and "Add To" block for customize article. So that the "Add To" block gets loaded before the "Add to Cart" block. 
In my template I saw that the blocks are loaded from container1.
Cataloge.xml showed me, that container1 is linked to product.info.options.wrapper.bottom . This file contains:

```
<div class="product-options-bottom">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true);?>
</div>
```

In my local.xml I edited:

```
<ajaxcart_index_options>
<reference name="content">
 <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml" translate="label">
            <label>Bottom Block Options Wrapper</label>
            <action method="insert"><block>product.tierprices</block></action>
            <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.clone_prices" as="prices" template="catalog/product/view/price_clone.phtml"/>
                <action method="append" before="addtocart"><block>product.info.addto</block></action>
                <action method="append" after="product.info.addto"><block>product.info.addtocart</block></action>
            </block>
</block>
</reference>
</ajaxcart_index_options>
```

I have no idea what I could do else, I tried after and before statements and I also placed the addto action block before the addtocart block, but nothing works.

Does anyone has an idea how I can change the load-order?

Thanks,
Simon

Answer (score 2):

Don't rely on `before` and `after` attributes because they only work with certain kinds of blocks (`core/text_list`). So your change as it is shouldn't have any result. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484955/magento-xml-using-before-after-to-place-blocks-hardly-ever-works

Instead, changing the order as you did, but in the right place, will work.

Try this in your `local.xml` (tested on mine and it is working):

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
        <reference name="content">
                <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info.options.wrapper.bottom" as="product_options_wrapper_bottom" template="catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml" translate="label">
                    <label>Bottom Block Options Wrapper</label>
                    <action method="insert"><block>product.tierprices</block></action>
                    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.clone_prices" as="prices" template="catalog/product/view/price_clone.phtml"/>
                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.addto</block></action>

                    <action method="append"><block>product.info.addtocart</block></action>
                </block>
       </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: I tried it and it crashed my whole template. :/ I guess the statements have to be in the Ajaxcart, because <ajaxcart_index_options> loads also a new template for the addtocart button and this is working.